# NotePad++ RegEx for Changing A Lot Of XREFs

Tags: xml, regex, notepad++

Below are several versions of XREF code used in a XML technical manual 3 tech writers are working on as a team. Obviously, it would have been great if they would have been consistent with their XREF syntax but they were not:

```
<xref figid="FIG_011"/>, 1
<xref figid="figure041"/> 8  (Please notice this XREF is missing a comma following the ">")
<xref figid="figure_025"/>, 4
```

When rendered to a PDF the XREF code above looks like this:

**Figure 3, 1**

**Figure 19 8**

**Figure 30, 4**

The objective now is to add the the word "Item" to precede the numbers "1, 8, and 4".  And if needed also a comma that follows the /> .  Below is what the RegEx needs to output:

**Figure 3, Item 1**

**Figure 19, Item 8**

**Figure 30, Item 4**

What I need the RegEx to FIND are these two parts of the XREF code:

```
<xref figid="   Also:  "/>
```

What I need the RegEx to IGNORE is:

All the text within the opening " (opening quotation mark) and closing " (closing quotation mark). Also the Item numbers located at the end such as "1, 8, and 4". All these characters differ from FigID to FigID and therefore need to be ignored by the RegEx. Also it needs to ignore a comma if it's already there (but on the flip side also add one if it's missing).

What I need the RegEx to REPLACE WITH is:

```
<xref figid="FIG_011"/>, Item 1
<xref figid="figure041"/>, Item 8 (Please notice the comma addition following the ">")
<xref figid="figure_025"/>, Item 4
```

There you have it. I hope my explanation has been clear and not confusing. The brick walls I have hit are mainly two.

First, how does one make a RegEx IGNORE characters that change from XREF to XREF instance and therefore only target the characters that remain consistent such as:

```
<xref figid="   Also:  "/>
```

Second, how do you give a RegEx the intelligence to know when to add  a comma or when not to so that it shows up on the PDF as shown in the example below:

**Figure 19, Item 8**

And not like this:

**Figure 19 Item 8**

Is coding this Either/Or functionality into a RegEx possible?  For that matter, is anything what I'm trying to do possible in a RegEx? I pray that it is because there are over 700 XREFs in the manual that need to be changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the structure of your XML markup, this is probably trivial to do with a regex find-and-replace.

> First, how does one make a RegEx IGNORE characters that change from XREF to XREF instance and therefore only target the characters that remain consistent such as:
>
> ```
> <xref figid="   Also:  "/>
> ```

You can use a wildcard match `.+?` to represent any characters within the `figid` attribute surrounded by quotation marks. The regex doesn't ignore the characters themselves so much as not care what they are; it'll pick them up regardless.

To capture and preserve the `<xref/>` tag along with its `figid` whatever value it may be, wrap it in `()`, and replace it with `$1` later.

> Second, how do you give a RegEx the intelligence to know when to add a comma or when not to so that it shows up on the PDF as shown in the example below:

You can use `,?` to optionally match a comma if it is there. This can be discarded, and a comma put in its place regardless of whether there is one or not.

Find:

```
(<xref figid=".+?"/>),?
```

Replace with:

```
$1, Item
```

Comment: BoltClock, thank you a million times for you post. I tried out your code and the result I got is: $1, Item 1 $1, Item 8 $1, Item 4. It did not preserve the <xref figid="   Also:  "/> . ANy suggestions?

Comment: @binar: Make sure you select Regular expression under Search Mode in the search dialog.

Comment: Shouldn't the  .+?  preserve the <xref figid=" Also: "/> ?

Comment: Yes,  I already made sure the Expression button was set to ON. I'm using NotePad++ v5.9.2.  Could this be the reason why it's not working?

Comment: Below is the data I'm testing your RegEx on:  <xref figid="FIG_011"/>, 1
<xref figid="figure041"/> 8 
<xref figid="figure_025"/>, 4

Comment: @binar: Yes, that could be it since Notepad++ 5.9 doesn't support `?` syntax. If you cannot upgrade to version 6.x, try changing `.+?` to `.+` and `,?` to `,*`. If each of your `<xref/>` tags is on its own line, this should not cause any problems.

Comment: Updating my NotePad++ right now to version 6. Because those changes still don't preserve the XML XREF code. I'll let you know what happens once update is completed.

Comment: BoltClock,  I updated to NotePad++ 6.3.3 and super happy to report that your RegEx worked like a charm. It preserves the XREF code mentioned earlier and it adds the missing comma.  This RegEx is one amazing piece of code.  I thank you a million times because this is going to enable me to fly through 700 XREF changes.  Again thank you very much. :-)